# Urllib working but Urllib2 is not

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to access a website via urllib2 via https command. If I use urllib, I get prompted for a username and password and then can access things fine. If I use urllib2, I setup an opener using the typical way but I still get a 401 error when I try to get a page. Any suggestions?  Do I need to change the password and username some way prior to using them?

Thanks!

```
def BuildOpener(): 
   pwmgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
   pwmgr.add_password(None, tlurl, USER, PASS)
   handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(pwmgr)
   opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
   Search_HTML = opener.open(BuildURL(cmd_type,param1,value1,param2,value2,sort_direction))
   return Search_HTML.read()
```